# Thread for reading from socket stream takes more CPU usage

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp, cpu-usage

In client socket, I wrote a thread to read the socket's inputStream continuously. Here I have used a while loop to read infinitely. However it takes more CPU; hence is it possible to reduce the CPU. Please add your suggestions.
Also is it possible to add listeners for inputStream.

**Thread code:**

```
public void run() {
while (!shutdown) {
    try {
        if(socketClient != null) {
            String message = socketClient.getMessage();
            logger.info ("Message size:" + message.length ());
            if(!message.equals("EmptyString")) {
                process(message);
            }
        } 
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        logger.info("Unable to read the socket message" +exception);
    }
}
```

}

**SocketClient.java**

```
public class SocketClient{
private volatile boolean isConnected;
private int              port;
private int              retryCount;
private long             startTime;
private String           hostName;
private DataInputStream  input;
private DataOutputStream output;
private Socket           socket;

public SocketClient(int port, String hostname) throws IOException {
    this.port     = port;
    this.hostName = hostname;
    establishConnection();
}


public void shutdown() {
    try {
        shutdown = true;
        input.close();
        output.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.debug("Exception in shutdown:" + e.getMessage());
    }
}

        public String getMessage() {
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new 
                        InputStreamReader(tcpSocket.getInputStream()));

        do {
            builder.append(reader.readLine());
        } while((reader.ready()));

        if (builder.length() == 0)
            return "EmptyString";

        return builder.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            return "EmptyString";
    } finally {
        try {
            if(reader != null)
                reader.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            logger.error("unable to close reader");
        }
    }
}

    private void establishConnection() {
        retryCount = 1;
        startTime  = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while (!shutdown) {
            try {
                if(!isConnected) {
                    socket = new Socket(hostName,port);
                    socket.setKeepAlive(true);
                    input       = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    output      = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    isConnected = true;
                    shutdown    = true;
                } 
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                isConnected = false;
                sleepFewSeconds();
                reconnectSocket();
            }
        }
    }

    private void reconnectSocket() {
        long endTime = startTime + 120000L;

        if(!(System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime)) {
            shutdown = true;
        }   
    }

    private void sleepFewSeconds() {
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(20);
        } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
            shutdown = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide an MCVE.  This code **doesn't** listen on an input stream.  What it actually does it check if a field of `sockekClient` ... and it will actually crash if the field is `null`.  This doesn't make a lot of sense, and it certainly doesn't allow us to understand what you are *really* doing.

Comment: I suggest that you sre ignoring end of stream and looping indefinitely when it occurs.

Comment: 'More CPU usage' than what? And what does [tag:thread-safety] have to do with it? 'Listen' is what `ServerSockets` do. This code *reads.* My suggestion stands. Your comment is not a question.

Comment: I have a socket client which establishes connection​ with server during startup.  And starts a thread which executes infinitely until we shutdown​ the application.Basically this thread continuosly trys to read the stream even if the stream is empty.My question: is there any other solution to read the socket only if the stream has data.? Also, does java java inputstream listener?

Comment: 'more cpu usage': it uses 100%of cpu

Comment: I have already made a suggestion. You cannot rationally expect anything but more guesswork unless you post a reproducible problem, as you were advised 11 hours ago. NB Input streams block while there is no data. The problem is in your code. NB 'more' is relative: '100%' is absolute. Say what you mean.

Comment: **There is nothing in your code or your edit that uses an `InputStream`.**

Comment: Added the code for reading inputStream. Please have a look and share your thoughts. 
I have another question: Normally if we use infinite loop inside thread, it takes more CPU. Correct me if I am wrong. Here my requirement is to read the stream only if the stream contains data. Hence thread executes only if the stream receives any data. Please add your suggestions

Comment: If you are able to understand my problem, then please remove the hold status

Comment: **It is exactly as I said yesterday.** You are swallowing `EOFException` in the inner code and returning null on any error, then in the calling code you are ignoring the null and continuing the loop on any error including end of stream, which is nonsensical. You are also misusing `available()`. Simply *remove* that test. Don't write code like this. And you are wrong. `InputStream.read()` *blocks* while there is no data, at least if you *call* it. But you are bypassing that by misusing `available()`, which gives your loop nothing else to do but spin.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the code now. Still I am facing the issue. Then I have removed the code for reading the socket which is available inside the while loop (thread). And added the println statement inside the while loop, still it takes same CPU. Here I need to read the sockets input stream continuously to check if the server puts any data in inputStream.  Do we have any other strategy other than infinite while looping

Comment: I can't comment on code I can't see. You should have already learnt this. The only code I can see here contains all the problems I have already enumerated.

Comment: Sorry, now I have added the updated code. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Why do you insist on calling methods like`available()` and `ready()`, instead of blocking in read, as you have been told to do here about six times? and why do you continue to ignore both end of stream and all exceptions, as you have also been told not to do about six times? You're making this so much more complicated than it really is, it is really quite incredible. `readLine()` already returns null at end of stream: you don't have to translate that into something else.

Comment: My understanding is, if the stream contains more bytes, we cant read in a single read. Thats why I have used ready() method.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again and again. if possible, can you please give detailed information to write that in simplified manner

Comment: If a 'message' is a single line, all you need instead of these two layers of code is `while ((line = in.readLine()) !=) null) { process(line); }`. If it isn't, you need to define here what a `message` is in your application protocol. Either way, ignoring end of stream and connection errors is not a correct approach. And `available()` and `ready()` are not message delimiters.

Comment: Thank you. Now I am able to understand. However my application needs to read message with multiple lines; here how we handle the end of stream and connection errors. It is a XML message with many tags.

Comment: So you should just connect the input stream direct to your XML parser. Don't get in the way at all.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation, EJP.

Comment: i see you are facing a lot of problem due to high disk usage of your system that many times leads to lagging.Well i have the solution to your problem i found this link on internet..really a helping article [http://errorcodespro.com/tiworker-exe-high-disk-usage-windows/](http://errorcodespro.com/tiworker-exe-high-disk-usage-windows/). At begining i thought it was because of hard drive failure but i applied the solution it worked very well. You can find your solution at the given system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to critique the entire class here. The answer to your specific question will appear.

```
public class SocketClient{
private volatile boolean isConnected;
```

You don't need this. `socket == null` would do just as well.

```
private int              port;
private int              retryCount;
private long             startTime;
private String           hostName;
private DataInputStream  input;
private DataOutputStream output;
private Socket           socket;

public SocketClient(int port, String hostname) throws IOException {
    this.port     = port;
    this.hostName = hostname;
    establishConnection();
}


public void shutdown() {
    try {
        shutdown = true;
        input.close();
        output.close();
        socket.close();
```

You don't need all these closes, and you're doing them in the wrong order anyway. `output.close()` is sufficient and in any case it should certainly be first.

```
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.debug("Exception in shutdown:" + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public String getMessage() {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
```

The `BufferedReader` should be an instance variable, not a local variable. It's buffered. If you make it a local variable you will lose data.

```
    try {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new 
                        InputStreamReader(tcpSocket.getInputStream()));

        do {
            builder.append(reader.readLine());
        } while((reader.ready()));
```

You don't need all this. If the message is a single line, all you need is `return reader.readLine()`, and you need the *caller* to check whether it was null, and if so close the socket, cease reading, etc. If the message is more than one line, this is a misuse of `ready()`: it is certainly *not* an indicator of end of message. It appears from comments under your question that you shouldn't even have the *method*: just connect the socket input stream directly to your XML parser and let *it* do the reading.

```
        if (builder.length() == 0)
            return "EmptyString";
```

Don't do this. Return `""` or null. Don't make up *new* magic strings for your application to have to decode.

```
        return builder.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            return "EmptyString";
```

Ditto.

```
    } finally {
        try {
            if(reader != null)
                reader.close();
```

You should *not* close the reader here. Closing it will close the socket, so you can never get another message.

```
        } catch(IOException e) {
            logger.error("unable to close reader");
        }
    }
}

private void establishConnection() {
        retryCount = 1;
        startTime  = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while (!shutdown) {
            try {
                if(!isConnected) {
                    socket = new Socket(hostName,port);
                    socket.setKeepAlive(true);
                    input       = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    output      = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    isConnected = true;
                    shutdown    = true;
```

Why are you setting `shutdown` to `true` here? Nothing is shutdown yet. It's a brand new socket.

```
                } 
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                isConnected = false;
                sleepFewSeconds();
                reconnectSocket();
            }
```

Poor practice. `Socket.connect()`, which is called internally by `new Socket(...)`, already retries, and also you should distinguish between connection-failure exceptions rather than adopt the same strategy for them all. For example, a 'connection timeout' will already have blocked for a minute or so: you don't need *another* sleep; and 'connection refused' means there is nothing listening, so retrying is completely pointless.

```
    private void reconnectSocket() {
        long endTime = startTime + 120000L;

        if(!(System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime)) {
            shutdown = true;
        }   
    }

    private void sleepFewSeconds() {
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(20);
```

This is not a 'few seconds'. It is 20 *milliseconds*, and that is not enough by at least two orders of magnite in network programming, to the extent that there should be any sleep at all of course.

```
        } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
            shutdown = true;
```

`shutdown` appears to be never false. I doubt that you've thought through what it really means, and I doubt that you really need it at all.

As for your calling code:

```
public void run() {
while (!shutdown) {
    try {
        if(socketClient != null) {
```

If `socketClient` is null this loop will spin meaninglessly. Surely this method should *construct* the socket client?

```
            String message = socketClient.getMessage();
            logger.info ("Message size:" + message.length ());
```

Here you are failing to check for null and failing to respond appropriately, which would be to close the socket and exit the loop. Instead you will get an NPE here.

```
            if(!message.equals("EmptyString")) {
                process(message);
```

See above. Don't send yourself special text messages. What happens if the peer needs to send that one day?

```
            }
        } 
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        logger.info("Unable to read the socket message" +exception);
```

Unacceptable. This catch is inside the loop and it essentially ignores the exception. The result is that, again, this loop will spin meaninglessly on any exception. And the methods you're calling should be declared to throw `IOException`, and that is all you should catch here. At present you will spin even on `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I have few questions: 1) while reading the socket, if it throws IO exception; then do we need to reconnect the server socket/ reintialize the socket again? 2) if we close the output stream, will it closes the socket? 3) if the message read from the inputstream is different as what we expected; do we have any standard to handle this?

Comment: @VishwaDany (1) Yes, unless it was merely a `SocketTimeoutException` when reading; (2) yes; (3) you've already asked that as a separate questlon.

Comment: Thanks a lot, EJP.